# Camera recognized but not showing in video devices

Tags: usb, webcam, camera

I am trying to open my usb camera in vscode using opencv, but my camera is not working.
I have an OAK-1 camera and when I connect my usb the camera it is recognized in
**Bus 001 Device 009: ID 03e7:2485 Intel Movidius MyriadX**:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 322e:202c Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 145f:0251 Trust Trust Wireless Keyboard and Mouse
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 03e7:2485 Intel Movidius MyriadX
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But running **ls /dev/video* ** it only appears to me my webcam.

```
ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0  /dev/video1
```

When passing command **lsusb -t**, my camera is recognized in the following line

```
Port 2: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
```

I am following this example to: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html
With id = 0 the code opens my webcam camera normally. I dont want to use the depthai library for now, just open the device as a normal camera with a simple opencv problem. Cheese app also does not show the my device.

Summarizing, how can I use my usb camera (Device 008) if it is not appearing in my list of video devices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very confusing question is there 1 camera or 2?

Comment: @David it is only one. One device node is for some metadata.

Comment: I have 1 usb camera. The devices in **ls /dev/video* ** are the built in webcam and the metadata. In other words, only the built in camera are appearing with the ls command.